# Adding SQL Objects to a JTable

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

So I'm currently working on a GUI for a school project, where we are making a Hotel Management System. Currently my task is to populate a jTable with some objects from our SQL database.

I have read up on it and the easiest way seems to be to use the `defaulttablemodel`, but I'm not sure how to incorporate that into my already existing [GUI](http://imgur.com/ukKIW52).

That is what my jForm currently looks like, not sure if that helps anyone at all, but at least it's a visual of what I'm trying to do.

And this is my "RoomMapper"

```
public class RoomMapper {

public ArrayList<Room> getRooms(Connection con) {

    ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList();

    String sqlString1
            = "select * from room "
            + "order by room_id";
    String sqlString2 = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES";

    PreparedStatement statement;
    try {

        statement = con.prepareStatement(sqlString1);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            i++;
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println("just added room nb " + i);
            rooms.add(new Room(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), 0, "stringy string"));
        }

        statement.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Fail in RoomMapper - getRooms");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("rooms arraylist size: " + rooms.size());
    return rooms;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a tablemodel

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
```

Create headers

```
String[] headers = {"1", "2"};
```

Set headers

```
model.setColumnIdentifiers(headers);
```

Populate the model

```
model.addRow(new Object[]{room.get1(), room.get2()});
```

Set tablemodel to the table

Comment: Thank you, this was a lot more comprehensive than a lot of the guides I've read.